# Asynchronous File Uploading in Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

How to upload files asynchronously in asp.net without postback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*> There is an AsyncFileUpload control in the Ajax control toolkit - AsyncFileUpload Sample.*

The control doesn't preserve query string on postback. So it's completely useless in current implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Flash ([for example](http://swfupload.org/)) for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to develop something which runs at client side (like Flash, Java, Silverlight) which breaks your files in chunks and send them directly to server in multiple requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have an open source control that does this in my site:

http://pjondevelopment.50webs.com/articles/asyncupload.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an AsyncFileUpload control in the Ajax control toolkit - [AsyncFileUpload Sample](http://www.asp.net/ajax/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx).
The toolkit is free and builds on top of the [MS ASP.NET AJAX Extensions](http://www.asp.net/ajax/). If you are using VS 2008 and .NET 3.5 then you already have the extensions installed.

Answer (score 0):

I use this works great plus it got multiple fileupload.
http://slfileupload.codeplex.com/